# What does window.close() do to the contents of said window?

Tags: window, titanium

I've got the below code:

```
// Initiate the font choosing lists.
var headerListWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow();

var headerFontListData = [{title:"Row 1"},{title:"Row 2"},{title:"Row 3"}];
var headerFontList = Titanium.UI.createTableView({data:headerFontListData});

chooseHeader.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    headerListWindow.left=win.width;

    var a = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    a.left = 0;
    a.duration = 1000;  

    headerListWindow.add(headerFontList);

    headerListWindow.open(a);
});

headerFontList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var a = Titanium.UI.createAnimation();
    a.left = win.width;
    a.duration = 1000;

    headerListWindow.close(a);
});
```

Which slides a window in nicely. When I open `headerListWindow` for the first time, everything appears, the list works, and the window slides in nicely. When I `close()` the window, however, all the list elements' names revert to "R.". Then, upon reopening the window, the list elements are completely gone. Why is this?

Comment: You are hiding the window which is already loaded in the screen. Thats why it is removing all the properties of the window object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

.close() kills your window.  it's passed on.  this window is no more.  It has ceased to be.  It's expired and gone to meet it's maker.  It's a stiff.  Bereft of life.  It rests in peace... etc.

when your window is closed, then your are destroying it.  You might like to try .hide() instead which will not null the window, but just not show it on the screen.

Comment: __Wat:__ "What do you mean, dead?"
__Roland:__ "The spark of his life is smothered in shite. His spirit is gone but his stench remains. Does that answer your question?"

Comment: you can use 

> window.visible = false 

instead of hide() methods as hide method does not work normally with big size window 
(window that contains a lot of children)

Answer (score 1):

blissapp, I am using the Alloy framework, and if I do a window.close() it does not kill the window. It closes the window, but if I log the window after it's still defined, and its definitely not dead.

I am not sure wether this applies to developing without alloy or not, but the object remains. You do have to re-open the window in order to render it, but it is my experience that the window is not deceased as you put it. I am definitely not destroying it.

An example:

```
welcome.addEventListener('open', function() {
    console.log("welcome is open");
    win1.close();
    Ti.API.debug(win1);
});
```

Outputs:

```
[INFO] :  welcome is open
[DEBUG] :  [object welcome]
```

Ofcause Nulling the variable is a solution, but why doesn't .close() work as it is suposed to according the documentation using Alloy? Am I missing something when working in Alloy?

Comment: I guess it is possible the object wasn't yet cleaned up by the environment so it persists.  I usually set all my windows to null after closing them, so I don't usually see that.